# How to programmatically minimize an iPad application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

How do I programmatically minimize an iPad/iPhone UIApplication?

Comment: Why do you want to "minimize"?  If it's to open some other app, that will happen automatically when you call a URL handler...

Answer (score 2):

Actually there no such method for minimize iPhone app.

You can try with "exit(0)" to close the app.

Cheers.

Comment: That would probably result in your app not being accepted on the store, though.

Comment: Yes, may be. But there is no other option.

Comment: Hi, I think there will be no chance of Reject. Please review below app on App Store:  "http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/knife-throw/id365462517?mt=8" .... Here, when you will play game and then Pause it then there is one option to Exit Game. So, it will close the game. So, apple may not reject. Hope it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can only switch to another app. I don't think apple has a public API for doing this.